# Running code whenever a notebook opens

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to run some code whenever I open a notebook in iPython notebook, basically I would like to specify a file or a couple lines of code to be executed before anything in that notebook is executed. The code is global, ie. should be executed for all notebooks when the iPython notebook server is started with this specific profile.

I have found settings to specify such startup script for the interactive shell, but not for the notebook part. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: The same settings for the IPython shell (e.g. [startup files](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html?highlight=startup%20files#startup-files) and `InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines`) should affect the notebook as well.

Comment: Thanks, the exec_lines with InteractiveShellApp works but the files in the startup dir are definitely not executed when opening a notebook

Comment: They definitely should be. If you can reproduce it, can you make an issue with details of what you're doing? https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues?state=open